How add R conda environment as R interpreter in PyCharm intellij?
The problem is that I cannot set the pycharm R interpreter with the created conda environments.
I have a windows machine. First I installed the R distribution on my machine in path (C:\programFiles\R ...). Then I installed pycharm and added the R plugin to that. Next installed anaconda and created a new environment with R version 4.1.3 while I have R version 4.4.1 on base environment. Then restarted pycharm and from bottom right corner I see R 4.4.1 from the local file is selected (in C:\programfiles...). When I chose to add local interpreter and navigated to the conda envs and picked R.exe from bin folder, the IDE throws
Invalid R interpreter (only R 3.4+ supported)
Cannot use this file as an R interpreter: Helper 'GetVersion.R' has non-zero exit code: -1073741515 Stdout: Stderr:

I have tried with most recent version of R 4.3.3 but still the same issue exists. What I am missing here? appreciate any help
